# Why isn't career 2.0 available for askubuntu users, why only for stackoverflow users?

Tags: feature-request

[Askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) is wholly and solely community dedicated to Ubuntu, why doesn't it provide career options in its field to reputed users like [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com). It would be great if we have website as http://careers.askubuntu.com and it would work the same way as http://career.stackoverflow.com .

Comment: I agree.  Especially that the jobs section contains jobs that are *not* for programmers....

Comment: Upvote, but I think there are more possible jobs where a programmer is useful than jobs for people with just Ubuntu knowledge... (?)

Comment: Yes, jobs opportunity could be provided to Linux users via Askubuntu careers (like shell programmer, Linux server admin, etc)

Comment: i have made a feature request here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251063/extend-careers-to-other-sites-like-ask-ubuntu-not-just-stack-overflow 
Hope the feature will be added

Comment: So I'm really confused - why don't you just sign up for SO careers?

Comment: SO careers require reputation in SO which i dont have