# Why didn't my reputation increase when my question was upvoted on meta?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I just posted a question on meta ([here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13667/why-isnt-career-2-0-available-for-askubuntu-users-why-only-for-stackoverflow-u?noredirect=1#comment23379_13667)) and it was upvoted thrice till now, still there is no change in my reputation.It didn't increase by 15.Why?

Comment: There is no reputation on meta.

Comment: Thank you, you may close the topic

Comment: my rep in AU is 798 but here it is 748 why didn't 50 rep today i gained add on meta ??